# Is there a maximum number of picklist items that are allowed in a Choice field?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a maximum number of picklist items that are allowed in a Choice field?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not have a built in limit for the number of Choice field options that can be added. We have tested up to 1000, but more can be used. I would like to note that adding large numbers can cause a slow down based on individual users computer, and internet connection.